# Function executes slowly from "on edit" trigger, but is fast if executed manually

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

The script is performing an "on edit" function that will change related fields depending on the value chosen by user. More or less, simple operations.

If executed by trigger, it takes from 8 to 20 seconds to execute.

If I run it manually (in regular or debug mode from the Script Editor), it completes in less than one second.

Any hint about what could be happening?

My function:

```
    function onOpen() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onEdit").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()).onEdit().create();
}

function onEdit(){
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var tabLists = "data-validation";


  // VALIDATION RULES FOR EXTENSIONS
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() >= 7){


    if (activeCell.getValue() != "") {

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xx").getSheetByName(tabLists);
      var packages = sheet.getRange(2, 4, 60, 1).getValues();


      var packageIndex = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], packages).indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;

      if (packageIndex != 0) {

        var packageIndexLast = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], packages).lastIndexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;


        var validationRange = sheet.getRange(packageIndex + 1, 5, (packageIndexLast - packageIndex + 1) , 1);
        var rangeData = validationRange.getValues().map(function(value,index) { return value[0]; });
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
        .requireValueInList(rangeData, true)
        .setAllowInvalid(false)
        .setHelpText("Pick an extension").build();


        activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearContent().clearDataValidations().setDataValidation(validationRule);

      }
    }
    else {
      activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: My crystal ball needs polishing - can't see anything in the code you didn't post here.

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch, i was trying to focus the issue in the difference between executing and debugging, since code is the same and performance is totally different. Perhaps the issue is related only to configuration, not the code itself, since performance should be the same in both cases if the issue was related to code...


Anyway, I have posted the edit function, just in case

Comment: I created 2 other spreadsheets, and ran your code in a third, perhaps 20 times from the ss as a user (with trigger On edit).  All the tests ran between 0.8 secs and 3 secs - mostly around 1 sec.

I also altered your code a bit, to eliminate repeated get (e.g. getValue()) where I thought they could be called just once and set as a var (plus I used e.value and e.range - I don't know if this helped a bit).  It ran even quicker, usually below 0.5 secs.

I didn't test from the debug

Comment: @davidmorales can you clarify the situations in which this runs slowly and in which it runs "normally"?

Comment: Thanks @DavidTew, i will check the code. My main problem is that when I execute the function from the script (execute or debug) it runs really fast, but from the excel itself is taking too much time.

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch, essentially it runs really slow when working with the excel itself. This is an edit function attached to a trigger, so everytime I change the record value is taking 15-20 seconds to execute the function.

On the other hand, when I execute the function from the script (execute or debug) it runs really fast.

Comment: How many spreadsheet formulas are recalculating when you edit the sheet cells that trigger this script? When you execute this function manually, Apps Script isn't waiting for cells to finish updating themselves.

Comment: Actually, no one @tehhowch,  Let me update the situation here:

1) I have created a different spreadsheet with only the edit function and teh specific affected rows.

2) Performance is still bad in that new spreadsheet when triggering the edit functioon from the spreadsheet. But fast when executing it from the script.

3) Something new is that when looking at executions, I see that when triggering edit function from the spreadsheet two executions are logged. One is failing the other is succesful. 
When I execute it from the script, only one execution (successful) is being logged.

Comment: 4) I have updated the code in the question to make it simpler, BTW